# meaning of "opposite sex" in everyday life

Tags: meaning

[urbandictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=opposite%20sex) explains "opposite sex" this way

> The opposite of sex (i.e. World of Warcraft).
>
> John: Hey dude, did you have teh sex on the weekend?
>
> Melvin: No, I had opposite sex.
>
> John: You mean Wow?
>
> Melvin: Yes, shut up.

I don't really understand that explanation. I know World of Warcraft is a massively multiplayer online role-playing game by Blizzard Entertainment. Does that explanation means that popular game is the opposite of sex?

It seems quite different to the meaning in other dictionaries, such as

> merriam-webster: the people who are not the same sex
>
> collinsdictionary: If you are talking about men and refer to the opposite sex, you mean women. If you are talking about women and refer to the opposite sex, you mean men.

Could some help me on this?

Comment: Urban Dictionary isn’t the most reliable source for definitions and learning English.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "opposite sex" literally means the "other" sex. If I'm a woman, the opposite sex is a man. If I'm a man, the opposite sex is a woman. However, it is also an old-fashioned term, usually used by men when they were talking about women.  For example, a man in the 1940s - 1970s might have said that he "enjoyed the company of the opposite sex" to mean that he loves being with (i.e. having sex with) women. So the phrase can have a sexual connotation.

The "opposite of sex" is a play on this phrase. It refers to something that men like to do that they think will never result in them actually meeting or having sex with a woman, such as playing video games.